# Same job uses different Access Paths in different servers in AS400

Tags: ibm-midrange

A Scheduled job in two different servers uses different access paths. Both are French Systems. What could be the reason for this? Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: Have you checked your job descriptions?

Comment: Are the user profiles the same?

Comment: Are the same logical files available for the system to chose from?

Comment: Are the servers running the same versions and updates?

Comment: That is a scheduled job that runs everyday.

Comment: same logical files exists in both the servers and both the servers are in same level

Comment: Also check job ccsid and/or table ccsid

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean a submitted job that's running database (probably SQL) code.

Do both access paths exist on both systems?

Have you tried running Visual Explain (part of ACS) with the query on both systems?  That will give you a lot of information about why specific access paths are chosen.

At the end of the day, does it mater? Is the correct data being retrieved?  If yes, then I would trust the SQE to choose the correct access paths.

Comment: Both the access paths exists in both the systems. Even with the query it is considering different access paths in different servers. It is fetching the data in different order in different servers as the access paths getting used in both the servers are different.

Comment: If you want the data in a specific order, you need to specify that order.  Otherwise the order is dependent on which access path it uses (or no access path, in which case it would use arrival sequence).

Comment: System is automatically considering different logical files in different systems. On what basis it considers different logical files?

Comment: Various considerations are used ... you can use the visual explain feature of iACS to see why access paths are used.  Again, if you want the data in a specific order, specify the order.  Don't worry about which access path the system uses.